# Number theory Problem .

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Given that $a,b$ are positive integers find all $(a,b)$ with the following conditions : 
$$(a+b)\mid(\gcd(a,b))^3 $$

Answer (score 2):

The best way to always start these problems is like this:

Let $\gcd(a,b) = d$. Then $a= a' d$ and $b= b'd$ with $\gcd(a', b')=1$.

So in your case you what to know when $a+b=d(a'+b')$ divides $\gcd(a,b)^3 = d^3$, in other words given $a'$ and $b'$ that are relatively prime, when does $(a'+b') \mid d^2$? This should tell you where to start.

Answer (score 1):

Write $g=\gcd(a,b)$ and $a=gn$, $b=gm$. Then $(a+b)\mid g^3\Leftrightarrow (n+m)\mid g^2$. Picking any coprime integers $n,m$, we can pick $g$ to be the square root of any perfect square divisible by $n+m$ - the set of such $g$ is the set of all multiples of the smallest such $g$. Define $\ell(n,m)$ to be the smallest number for which $\ell^2$ is divisible by $n+m$ (this is $(n+m)\displaystyle\prod_{2\nmid v_p(n+m)}p$). Then

$$\{(a,b)\in\Bbb N^2:(a+b)\mid \gcd(a,b)^3\}=\{(k\,\ell(n,m)\,n,\,k\,\ell(n,m)\,m):n,m,k\in\Bbb N,\gcd(n,m)=1\}.$$